# Empty space, colon and semi colon trigger Disallowed Key Characters in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The application has been working fine for months and suddenly (without any changes to the environment) in the past few days I started getting the "Disallowed Key Characters" in CI. I've read all the related topics here about this problem and I understand that adding the character that triggers the exception is the answer to my question. However I'm not an expert in security so I wanted to consult it with people who have more experience in this matter. In my case the string that gets caught is the following:

```
"--------------------------31329b0d7bb66ba6
```

Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"

As I thoroughly checked, CI doesn't like 3 characters here; the space, semi colon and colon. Is it safe to add these like I did in my example here:

[enter link description here](http://goo.gl/Znn2DD)

Also, how is that possible that the problem started happening recently without any code & env changes?

Update 1:

After adding the change it looks like something gone wrong. $_POST variables are not what they supposed to be. When I do print_r($_POST); I get the following:

```
Array
```

(
    [--------------------------9926a756dcff6e27

Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "tracking_number"

94001102008297123
--------------------------9926a756dcff6e27
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="carrier"

USPS
--------------------------9926a756dcff6e27--

)

Answer (score 1):

The moral of the story is that the data encoding on the client side were being submitted in Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded after vs Content-Type: multipart/form-data

After I changed the encoding on the client side I was able to remove the colon, semi colon and the space from the cleansing function.